# In string theory, can strings have zero string tension?

Tags: string-theory

Energy = length * string tension

Is it possible for a string to have zero tension, or is it possible that its tension decreases while maintaining length or even growing in length?

Comment: The tension in a string is due to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. So the quick answer is no.

Comment: Tensionless strings are often discussed in literature, often simply as the $\alpha'\to\infty$ limit of string theory. More recently there is on-going research about how to define tensionless strings intrinsically as opposed to a limit. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04361

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you mean by *tension*. [As Luboš Motl describes here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/3347/1325), the Nambu-Goto string action is:

$$ S_{NG} = -\frac{T_0}{c}\int d\mathcal A \tag{1} $$

where the constant $T_0$ has the units of a tension, and this is what we call the string tension. This is a fundamental constant so it cannot change at all, let alone become zero.

However in string theory we can have open strings, and obviously the *effective tension* at the ends of the string must be zero otherwise the tension would pull in the ends and the string would contract away to nothing. If $v$ is the perpendicular velocity of the string then the effective tension is:

$$ T_{eff} = T_0 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} \tag{2} $$

The ends of an open string have $v = c$, and substituting this into equation (2) gives us:

$$ T_{eff} = 0 $$

So in this sense the tension in a string can be zero at the ends of an open string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems relevant to mention that there exist in the literature theories for [tensionless strings](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=tensionless+strings) and for null strings. E.g. in the [Hamiltonian formulation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184742/2451) of the bosonic string, the Virasoro constraints are then changed into $$\begin{align*}0~\approx~\chi_1&:=~P\cdot X^{\prime} ,\cr0~\approx~\chi_2&:=~P^2+T_0^2(X^{\prime})^2~ \longrightarrow ~ P^2\qquad\text{for}\qquad T_0~\equiv~\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar c\alpha^{\prime}}~\to~ 0.\end{align*}$$

References:

1. A. Schild, *Classical null strings,* [Phys.Rev. D16 (1977) 1722](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.1722).
2. A. Bredthauer, U. Lindström, J. Persson & L. Wulff, *Type IIB tensionless superstrings in a pp-wave background,* [arXiv:hep-th/0401159](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401159).
3. U. Schrieber, [*The string coffee table blog*](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/string/archives/000453.html), 2004.

(See also references within Refs. 1-3.)